How to implement 3d hover effect on text in react
How can I implement this effect in react native, check image for better understanding
I want to build a hover effect on text that when I hover on a text it goes in a 3d like effect in react js as in the image when I hover on the text it goes in 3d like text

Please provide some code, displaying what you've already tried. It is pretty hard for us to come with a solution by just guessing your implementation.

I tried to do it box-shadows:
text-shadow:
0 1px 0 rgb(190,190,190),
0 2px 0 rgb(190,190,190),
...;
But i didnt work when i add skew()
